# Facebook post using ShareKit working only for Facebook ID of created App

Tags: ios, facebook, share, sharekit

I am using ShareKit for sharing a post with a message & URL on
 Facebook. The code snippets using which the code works is as below

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringurl]; 
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:stringtitle contentType:SHKURLContentTypeWebpage];

SHKSharer* sharer = [[NSClassFromString(@"SHKiOSFacebook") alloc]init];
[sharer loadItem:item];
[sharer share];
```

On button click, the application looks up for the **Facebook id** which
  has been configured in **Settings** of the **Simulator or Phone**. On allowing access, it launches a popup having post contents. 
 
My problem is that this is
  working **only for the Facebook ID using which I have created the application on facebook developers console** . 
 I am not finding the settings on facebook developer site or inside ShareKit to enable posting to any Facebook users wall. So how can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post to another user's wall using ShareKit, or Graph API.

The only way to achieve this is to use the Feed Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: I am not trying to post to other user's wall, but on the wall of user whose account has been added in the Facebook section of iOS settings. The call to post URL works only for the Facebook account ID using which I have created the Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. Sandbox Mode is a settings in Facebook App which was enabled. It has to be disabled.